# Story (novel) about immortal people who can turn into dragons

Tags: story-identification

I read this story probably ~15-20 years ago - I don't know if the story is much older. I believe the story is in the form of a novel and not a short story, but I'm not 100% sure. The plot details I can remember are:

- There are immortal people who can turn into dragons.
- The protagonist was one of them.
- The protagonist wasn't really a "good" person. I think none of these
  "species" are "good".
- An antagonist (can't remember if it was the main antagonist) was also
  one of them.
- The protagonist "kills" this antagonist by ripping his body apart
  into many pieces. I think even then the antagonist isn't "dead", but
  just neutralized (he's immortal after all).
- The protagonist has been around for ~thousands of years (not 100%
  sure on exactly how long, but I do recall it was a long time - longer
  than a normal human lifetime at least).
- The protagonist may have longed for death.
- I think it was a story directed at young adults. I was really into
  Dragon-Lance at the time so I probably read this story expecting a
  similar kind of experience. -- MIGHT BE FALSE
- Pretty sure the events of the story happens in a (my impression is modern) city - not a rural area - but I can't remember which city (or if it was really modern).
- The protagonist is more senior (older) than the antagonist.
- I think the members of this species might all serve some much more ancient/powerful being but I don't remember any specifics on that.
- I'm pretty sure the cover was dark and featured a dragon.
- I think the novel was pretty explicit now that I'm thinking more...perhaps with explicit sex scenes or explicit violence and gore. This would suggest the novel is NOT for young adults...but I really can't remember unfortunately...

That's as many details as I can remember right now. If I think of more, I'll update.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: @Valorum In fact I did look through that checklist to help me write this question. The provided details are as much as I can remember at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

**Roadmarks** by Roger Zelazny is close.   One of the memorable characters was 
a book, **Flowers of Evil** with some real... depth.   The setting,
a road of mystical properties, is not exactly rural, but not urban either.
The cover sported a dragon, and becoming/maturing is  the main plot element.

Comment: That was my first guess, based just on the title of the question, but there's a lot of other stuff that does not seem to fit.

Comment: I don't think that's the one...I've read the descriptions and none of it is really ringing any bells. But looking at the cover, it does jog a memory that the cover I remember is quite dark. There's a dragon on the cover (I think) set against a dark background. I'll add it to the details. Unfortunately, since my memory of this novel is so poor, I'm not actually sure I'm remembering any of this correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible you're remembering various scenes from **Steven Erikson's Malazan series**?

- There are immortal people who can turn into dragons.

Yes, lots. They're called soletaken.

- The protagonist was one of them.

One of the protagonists of Book 1 ("Gardens of the Moon") is Anomander Rake. There are various people throughout the series who could be called protagonists who are also soletaken.

- The protagonist wasn't really a "good" person. I think none of these
  "species" are "good".

The series has very few people on the extreme ends of the good/evil spectrum.

- An antagonist (can't remember if it was the main antagonist) was also
  one of them.
- The protagonist "kills" this antagonist by ripping his body apart
  into many pieces. I think even then the antagonist isn't "dead", but
  just neutralized (he's immortal after all).

These two dot points sort of sound like the prologue of Book 5 ("Midnight Tides"). Scabandari Blood-Eye "kills" Silchas Ruin in a manner similar, though not exactly, to what you describe. Even then Silchas Ruin doesn't die.

- The protagonist has been around for ~thousands of years (not 100%
  sure on exactly how long, but I do recall it was a long time - longer
  than a normal human lifetime at least).

The life-span of several characters, including the soletaken, in the Malazan books stretches back hundreds of thousand years.

- The protagonist may have longed for death.

This describes Anomander Rake, who:

> has grown weary over the millennia and sacrifices himself in Book 8 ("Toll the Hounds")

- I think it was a story directed at young adults. I was really into
  Dragon-Lance at the time so I probably read this story expecting a
  similar kind of experience. -- MIGHT BE FALSE

Malazan series is certainly not YA.

- Pretty sure the events of the story happens in a (my impression is
  modern) city - not a rural area - but I can't remember which city (or
  if it was really modern).

The first book was mainly set in the city of Darujhistan. Some of the other books were also largely city-based.

- The protagonist is more senior (older) than the antagonist.
- I think the members of this species might all serve some much more
  ancient/powerful being but I don't remember any specifics on that.

These clues don't quite match the Malazan series.

- I'm pretty sure the cover was dark and featured a dragon.

None of my editions feature a dragon. However many of them are dark. A quick google check doesn't find any editions with dragons, however some feature creatures that look vaguely dragon-like.

- I think the novel was pretty explicit now that I'm thinking
  more...perhaps with explicit sex scenes or explicit violence and
  gore. This would suggest the novel is NOT for young adults...but I
  really can't remember unfortunately...

No sex in the Malazan series but plenty of violence.